# Endomorphism ring of a quiver representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

Consider the quiver with one loop, and consider the representation on $\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)$ described by the matrix $$W=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ I need to calculate the endomorphism ring of this representation. I was able to calculate this on $\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)$, but now I need to calculate it one The algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)$. I'm stuck.

Comment: What did you obtain for $\Bbb F_2(t)$? By "closure" you mean an algebraic closure?

Comment: yes I mean the algebraic closure. For $\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)$ I obtained the span of the identity and the matrix W itself.